# using twitter api with firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have been assigned on a task to fetch all tweets from a certain hashtag and send that data to my application. So I decided to use firebase cloud functions, I generated the key needed for the twitter api. I also tested get my homepage using postman status and worked, however my issue now when I test my code on good cloud functions I cant get it to work and the error message when I try this end point:

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

> https://us-central1-don.cloudfunctions.net/api/

or

> https://us-central1-don.cloudfunctions.net/api/statuses/user_timeline

and this is my code on firebase cloud functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const Twitter = require('twitter');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



const client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    consumer_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    access_token_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});

const app = express();

/* Express */

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: 'nodejs', count: 5}, function (error, tweets, response) {

        if (!error) {
            response.send({ title: 'Express', tweets: tweets })
        }
        else {
            response.send({ error: "this is error: " + error })
        }
    });
});
// Cloud Function
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Hope anyone can suggest any solutions, thanks.

Update: here is my function console where it also throws an error:

> api Function execution took 8 ms, finished with status code: 404
>
> api Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible
>   and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove
>   these restrictions

Comment: Aren't you running the Free plan ? If so, outbound requests are limited to Google's services : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680257/firebase-cloud-functions-throws-a-dns-error-when-calling-an-external-api

Comment: @PhilippeSultan yes i am on free plan, thanks for the help, i'll upgrade my account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should upgrade to a paid plan, you may find this other Stack Overflow question useful : [Cloud Functions for Firebase - Billing account not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784135/cloud-functions-for-firebase-billing-account-not-configured)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, i have not tested the solution yet, but ill mark this is an answer once I do. thanks.